# Is there a way define complex where conditions as variables?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, apollo-client, laravel-lighthouse

I have created a GraphQL Query that gets complex where conditions but in Apollo GraphQL iOS client there is no way of changing query after compiling the project. Apollo GraphQL iOS client gives chance to change defined variables in the query but not the query itself.

My original Lighthouse GraphQL query is like following;

```
query ($first:Int, $page:Int) {
    my_listings(
        where: {
            AND: [
                { column: NET_AREA, operator: GTE, value: 200 }
            ]
        }
        orderBy: [
            { column: ID, order: ASC }
            ]
        first: $first
        page: $page
    ) {
        data {
            ...listingFields
        }
        paginatorInfo {
            currentPage
            lastPage
        }
    }
}
```

Altered Lighthouse GraphQL query is like this, only added $conditions variable which is `MyListingsWhereWhereConditions` type.

```
query($first: Int, $page: Int, $conditions:MyListingsWhereWhereConditions) {
  my_listings(
    where: $conditions
    orderBy: [{ column: ID, order: ASC }]
    first: $first
    page: $page
  ) {
    data {
      ...listingFields
    }
    paginatorInfo {
      currentPage
      lastPage
    }
  }
}
```

When I give the following variables into the second query Lighthouse server returns me the following message

```
{
  "first": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "conditions": {"AND": {"column": "PRICE", "operator": "LTE","value": "190"}}
}
```

error message

```
Variable \"$conditions\" got invalid value {\"AND\":{\"column\":\"PRICE\",\"operator\":\"LTE\",\"value\":\"190\"}}; Expected type MyListingsWhereWhereConditions to be an object at value.AND.column.
```

Is there a way of giving these conditions in a variable ? Without it I couldn't find a way of changing where condition on iOS client.

Comment: that is no PHP error that is a wrong query ...

Comment: Maybe post the complete SDL of the MyListingsWhereWhereConditions input type? Seems like it expects the value for column to be an object, not an enum.

Comment: AND should be an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AND" should contain array of objects, not object.

```
"conditions": {"AND": [{"column": "PRICE", "operator": "LTE","value": "190"}}]
```